# Ruby on Rails / MySQL error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded my Mac to 10.9, Mavericks, and everything went downhill from there.  I wish I could easily downgrade and go back.  So, after days of troubleshooting, I finally got the rails server to run and I can see my app locally on localhost. But now I am getting a MySQL error (see below) when I try to run the "rails console" command:

/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]

Any advice / help on this one would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you install mysql? homebrew? if so, you'll want to brew doctor.  I had a ton of problems after upgrading to Mavericks but after a week I was back up - hang on!

Comment: Tx but I tried the brew doctor and still the same results.  I ended up fixing this by reinstalling the latest Ruby version and making the default Ruby version 2.0.0p451 for Mavericks.  Then I reinstalled MySQL and all of my gems and all is working fine, just like it did before the upgrade.